# How to edit all keys in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having some trouble with mongoose. I'm trying to change all keys' values in an array.
I searched for solutions and I tried many different queries but it did not work correctly.

```
[
 {
  _id: ID,
  name: 'Matt',
  groups: [
   {group_name: 'Group 1', status: true},
   {group_name: 'Group 2', status: true}
  ]
 }
]
```

I'm trying to select Matt by _id and turn all status' keys false in groups array.

Here the final query I tried:

```
People.updateMany({'_id': req.params.id}, {$set: {'groups.$.status': false}}, {multi: true})
```

Do you have any idea about what's missing here?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on `$[]` [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)

> The all positional operator $[] indicates that the update operator should modify all elements in the specified array field

so just try

```
db.getCollection('collection').updateMany({'_id': req.params.id}, 
{$set: {'groups.$[].status': false}},
{multi: true})
```